# Why is not swap done?

Tags: c++, struct, reference, pass-by-reference, swap

Not exchanged

```
void f(struct a s)
{
    int t;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (s.b[j] > s.b[j + 1]) {
                s.c = s.b[j];
                s.b[j] = s.b[j + 1];
                s.b[j + 1] = s.c;
            }
        }
}
```

The output is expected to be arranged, but it is exactly the same as the input

Comment: Hard to say exactly what the problem is, because the example seems incomplete. But it's likely because you are passing some `a` to `f` and then checking it for changes but `f`'s `s` is taken by value.

Comment: There is no output here, nor any input. But as a guess, the function takes its argument by value, so any changes won't propagate back to the caller.

Comment: If you want to swap two values, what you *should* be using is [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters it seems that the function has undefined behavior if the array `s.b` has exactly `10` elements because at least in this statement

```
if (s.b[j] > s.b[j + 1]) {
                 ^^^^^^
```

there is an attempt to access memory beyond the array when `j = 9` (there is no element with the index `10` in the array)

Declare the inner loop at least the following way

```
    for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
        if (s.b[j - 1] > s.b[j]) {
            s.c = s.b[j];
            s.b[j] = s.b[j - 1];
            s.b[j - 1] = s.c;
        }
```

Also it is not clear why the data member `s.c` that is used in fact as a temporary object is declared within the structure. It should be removed from the structure definition and within the loop some local variable should be used instead. For example

```
        if (s.b[j - 1] > s.b[j]) {
            auto tmp = s.b[j];
            s.b[j] = s.b[j - 1];
            s.b[j - 1] = tmp;
        }
```

And you passed the object by value. So the function deals with a copy of the original object.

Pay attention to thet there is standard c++ function `std::swap` that does the same.
For example

```
std::swap( s.b[j], s.b[j - 1] );
```

By the way the variable `t` is not used in the function.

Declare the parameter as having a referenced type.

```
void f(struct a &s);
```

or alternatively through a pointer to the structure

```
void f(struct a *s);
```

In this case to access data members of the structure you should write for example

```
s->b[j - 1]
```

Also it is a bad idea to use a magic number like `10`. You could declare within the structure a static data member for example like

```
static const int N = 10;
```

and use the variable `N` in the loops.

For example

```
void f(struct a &s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a::N; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < a::N; j++) {
            if (s.b[j - 1] > s.b[j]) {
                auto tmp = s.b[j];
                s.b[j] = s.b[j - 1];
                s.b[j - 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. struct a{int b[10] and int c;} and this is buble sort .what the Problem

Comment: @Matin.sadeghi Declare the structure at least like struct a
{
    static const int N = 10;
    int b[N];
}; provided that you compile the program as indeed C++ program.

Answer (score 5):

```
void f(struct a s)
```

`s` is passed by value, which copies its contents. You need to pass it by reference or by address to modify the caller's original struct.

```
void f(struct a& s)
```

or

```
void f(struct a* s)
...
f(&s);
```

Comment: Or `return` the modified object.